# Is it possible that a standard http server respond to the second request before first request on the same channel?

Tags: http

Is it possible that a standard http server respond to the second request before respond to the first request on the same channel?
Just like:
1. server recieve request1 on channel1
2. server recieve request2 on channel1
3. server respond request2 with response2 on channel1
4. server respond request1 with response1 on channel1

can this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can happen. 
Each request received by server are executed in different thread or different instance.

for example, the first request may require access to database for finding data. this will take some time based on database size or connectivity.  since it access database it may take 2 seconds.

the second request may get the data that is already cache in the server which will takes less then 1 second.

so the second request will complete before the first request.